# Example of a function with $f^\prime (x)=f^\prime(1-x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a strictly descending continuous function such that $f^\prime(x)=f^\prime(1-x)$ for all $x$. Obviously $f(x)=1-x$ is an example of these functions. Is there another example? Can we characterize all of these functions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure the example given works. With $f(x)=1-x$ then $f'(x)=-1$ but $f(1-x)=1-(1-x)=x$ so $f'(1-x)=1$.

Comment: Be sure. $f^\prime (1-x)=-1$ and $[f(1-x)]^\prime =1$.

Comment: But then how is $f'(x)=f'(1-x)$ when $-1 \neq 1$ for all $x$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f'(x+1/2)$ is an even function on $[-1/2, 1/2]$, so $f(x+1/2)-f(1/2)$ is an odd function.  Any strictly decreasing, differentiable odd function $g$ on $[-1/2, 1/2]$ will do, and then take $f(t) = g(t - 1/2) + c$ where $c \ge -g(1/2)$.